# TypeConverter in propertygrid only converts from string, not to

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid, typeconverter

Only the ConvertTo method gets called(a lot of times) when accessing the propertygrid. This correctly returns the "Foo!" string in the propertygrid. When I click to edit I get an exception `Cannot convert object of type Foo to type System.String.`(not exactly, translated). The ConvertFrom method doesn't get called, any clues why? And the error indicates it's trying to convert TO a string, not from.

I would think when I want to edit this object, it has to convert from Foo to string, and when finished editing back.

StringConverter class:

```
public class FooTypeConverter : StringConverter {
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        return new Foo((string) value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        return "Foo!";
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Property being accessed:

```
Foo _foo = new Foo();
[Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(FooTypeConverter))]
public Foo Foo {
    get {
        return _foo;
    }
    set {
        _foo = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out it has something to do with the MultilineStringEditor, if I disable that, it works correctly.

Comment: I only just saw your update; you are going to have to write your own editor - `MultilineStringEditor` is **not** going to know how to process a `Foo`, so is either saying "no", or an exception is being raised and handled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re your update; here's a `FooEditor` that should work as a shim:

```
class FooEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    MultilineStringEditor ed = new MultilineStringEditor();
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        Foo foo = value as Foo;
        if (foo != null)
        {
            value = new Foo((string)ed.EditValue(provider, foo.Value));
        }
        return value;        
    }
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return ed.GetEditStyle();
    }
    public override bool  IsDropDownResizable {
        get { return ed.IsDropDownResizable; }
    }
}
```

You'll obviously need to associate it:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FooTypeConverter))]
[Editor(typeof(FooEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
class Foo { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: That seems to do it, thanks! I was thinking I could use BOTH a UITypeEditor and a TypeConverter.

Comment: @Robert - you still can ;-p Don't forget some other controls (`DataGridView` etc) will only use the converter, not the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce; it works fine for me; you should be testing the `destinationType` and type of `value`, btw - but that isn't stopping it calling `ConvertFrom`. Do you have a complete example (perhaps based on the following) that shows it **not** calling `ConvertFrom`?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class FooTypeConverter : StringConverter {
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return new Foo("FooTypeConverter.ConvertFrom: " + Convert.ToString(value));
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return "FooTypeConverter.ConvertTo: " + ((Foo)value).Value;
    }
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
[TypeConverter(typeof(FooTypeConverter))]
class Foo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Foo(string value) { Value = value; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Foo.ToString";
    }
}
class Test
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        using(Form form = new Form())
        using (PropertyGrid grid = new PropertyGrid())
        {
            grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            grid.SelectedObject = new Test { Foo = new Foo("Main") };
            form.Controls.Add(grid);
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```